# Equivalent of `git add --force` to add ignored files in Emacs' Magit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I have a rule in my `.gitignore` to ignore `.pdf` files in my current git repo. But I'd like to add a `pdf` in particular to my commit (`example.pdf`). I'm working with Emacs and [Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit).

In a Linux terminal I would usually type:

`git add example.pdf --force`

Although, I haven't found an equivalent way of doing so in Magit.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magit is very customizable.  One clean method of adding this functionality would be to add an "Ignored" section to the magit status buffer.

Do this by adding a hook to `magit-status-sections-hook` to insert and populate a magit section.  The code here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28506/2731 is probably exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying your `.gitignore` file to exclude `example.pdf` (and possibly other files) from being excluded:

```
# Ignore PDF
*.pdf

# But exclude certain files
!example.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

From time to time, I also have to add a single ignored file to my git repo. I use the following function:

```lisp
  (defun magit-add-current-buffer ()
    "Adds (with force) the file from the current buffer to the git repo"
    (interactive)
    (shell-command (concat "git add -f "
               (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))))
```